# Check if email address already exists in the database using jQuery and PHP.return false is not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery ajax return: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580265/jquery-ajax-return-undefined)

I have written the following code to check email already exists or not using jquery and jquery validate.Jquery is used for email format validation.
I have called ****check-email.php** file in **jquery function**.even though there emailaddress is present in my db,the action is get called and it directs to dashboard page.Actually it should not direct to next page because email is already exists.**My **"return false;"** in jquery function has no effect.It goes to next page even if it is present in db. I am not getting where I am wrong ???

here is my code

index.html:-

```
<form name="mysignupform" id="mysignupform" class="form-horizontal"  action="Dashboard" method="post">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail" >Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="inputEmail"  placeholder="Email" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword" >Password</label>

 <div class="controls">

 <input class="password" type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">


    </div>

    </div>


    <div class="controls">
      <input type="hidden" id="body" name="body" value=""></input>
    </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">

      <button type="submit" name="submit" id="signupsubmit"class="btn btn-inverse" onsubmit="return function(e)">Go to Dashboard</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

my jquery function:-

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 

           $('#signupsubmit').click(function() 

         {
             alert('in');

             var emailVal = $('#inputEmail').val(); // assuming this is a input text field

             alert(emailVal);
             $.post('check-email.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {

             if(data=='true') return false;
             else $('#mysignupform').submit();

          });

       });

    });
</script>
```

my check-email.php:-

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

   if (!$con)
  {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
       mysql_select_db("mojiva", $con);

       $sql = "SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email =".$_POST['email'];

       $select = mysql_query($sql,$con);

       $row = mysql_num_rows($select);

            if ($row > 0)  
          {
            echo 'true';  
          }
             else 
          {
             echo 'false';
          }

?>
```

I tried true false in jquery function immediate after $('#signupsubmit').click(function() this function at this time return true works.but when post is get called it does not have any effect of return false.

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and are exposing yourself to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the return false is not referring to the form but the click event.

On the form:

```
<form name="mysignupform" id="mysignupform" class="form-horizontal"  action="Dashboard" method="post" onsubmit="email_check($('#inputEmail').val())" >
```

Then for JQuery:

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 

          function check_email(emailVal){ 

         {
             alert('in');

             alert(emailVal);
             $.post('check-email.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {

             if(data=='true') return false;
             else return true;

          });

     }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line by change "type" from submit to button.

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id="signupsubmit" class="btn btn-inverse" onsubmit="return function(e)">Go to Dashboard</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the form submission, you need to prevent the click from bubbling up:

```
$('#signupsubmit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do your ajax here
}
```